# Importing Data from another class to Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, google-signin

I'm authenticating a user on one screen then pushing them to another screen but on the other screen  the variable is not accessible which contains user details which I've passed through a variable. `detailsUser` is not accessible in the Home(); and even though I've mentioned to push on another page. It authenticates and doesn't take me to another screen.

```
class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInScreenState createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async{
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Signed In'
    );

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        accessToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    FirebaseUser userDetails = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)) as FirebaseUser;
    ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

    List<ProviderDetails> providerData = List <ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = UserDetails(
      userDetails.providerId,
      userDetails.displayName,
      userDetails.photoUrl,
      userDetails.email,
      providerData);

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThemeConsumer(child: Home(detailsUser: details))));

    return userDetails;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
```

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser;

  Home({Key key, @required this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
     child: Text(
     detailsUser.username //detailsUser is not accessible here, why?
)));
```

Comment: use this "widget.detailsUser.username" instead of "detailsUser.username"

Comment: @PatelPinkal Thanks, it worked. I've updated question with one more issue. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Use directly Home instead of "ThemeConsumer". Like : Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(detailsUser: details)));

Comment: @PatelPinkal why didn't you post an answer?

Comment: @PatelPinkal tried. Still same. It authenticates and stays on the same screen.

Comment: @codekls, Just try to open screen form the same method but without authenticates. Is that working or not?

Comment: @PatelPinkal it doesn't. I'll probably try another method as this didn't work. I'm struggling to sign in user with google.

Comment: @codekls, before you authenticate and move to the next screen, you must be sure that your method is working to open another screen without authenticating.

Answer (score 1):

To access the `Widget` fields from within the `State class` of that widget, you can use `widget.fieldName` (as Patel Pinkal commented)

here is a [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development) to get more familiar with widgets in flutter

Answer (score 1):

As Patel Pinkal said in comments:

```
Use this "widget.detailsUser.username"
```

instead of

```
"detailsUser.username"
```